# i cant save and update data using modal and bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i'm so confused. i currently do a project for my final exam. 
i'm so newbie using php, modal, and jquery. i really need your help.
the problem is, i'm using bootstrap validator to validate my form, but after i using it, i cant save my data to my database. and my edit button not working well, i guess i've throw my button to my edit process.
please help. thanks

listadmin.php

```js
<script>

  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "responsive": true,
      "autoWidth": false
    });
  });
</script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
                $(".open_modal").click(function (e){
                    var m = $(this).attr("username");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "user_edit.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        data : {username: m,},
                        success: function (ajaxData){
                            $("#ModalEdit").html(ajaxData);
                            $("#ModalEdit").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

   $(document).ready(function (){
                $(".open_delete").click(function (e){
                    var m = $(this).attr("username");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "user_delete.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        data : {username: m,},
                        success: function (ajaxData){
                            $("#ModalDelete").html(ajaxData);
                            $("#ModalDelete").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
  $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#form-save')
                    .bootstrapValidator({
                        message: 'This value is not valid',
                        feedbackIcons: {
                            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                        },
                         submitButtons: 'button[type="submit"]',
                        fields: {
                            username: {
                                message: 'Username tidak valid',
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'Username tidak boleh kosong'
                                    },
                                    stringLength: {
                                        min: 5,
                                        max: 30,
                                        message: 'Panjang minimal 5 karakter dan panjang maksismu 30 karakter'
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 
                            

                            nama_lengkap: {
                                message: 'Nama Lengkap tidak valid',
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'Nama Lengkap tidak boleh kosong'
                                    },
                                    stringLength: {
                                       
                                        max: 50,
                                        message: 'Panjang maksimal 50 karakter'
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 

                            password: {
                                message: 'Password tidak valid',
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'Password tidak boleh kosong'
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            level: {
                                message: 'Level tidak valid',
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'Level belum dipilih'
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 


                        }

                    });

                });

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>List Admin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  


  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


 
<section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          
          <!-- /.box -->

          <div class="box">
              <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">List User</h3>
          </div>
  
        <div class="box-body">
        
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tambah" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Tambah User</a>


        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nomor</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Nama Lengkap</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Action</th>   
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <?php 
          include "connection.php";
          $query_mysql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM master_user where status='0'")or die(mysqli_error());
          $nomor = 1;
          while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_mysql)){
          ?>

          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $nomor++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['nama_lengkap']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['password']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['level']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" class='btn btn-primary open_modal' username='<?php echo $data['username']; ?>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Edit</a> |
              <a href="#" class='btn btn-danger open_delete' username='<?php echo $data['username']; ?>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Hapus</a>        
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>

        <div class="example-modal">
              <div class="modal fade" id="tambah" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Tambah User</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body form">
                        <form action="user_save.php" id="form-save" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                          <div class="form-body">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-9">
                                      <input name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" type="text">
                                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nama Lengkap</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-9">
                                      <input name="nama_lengkap" placeholder="Nama Lengkap" class="form-control" type="text">
                                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-9">
                                      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
                                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Level</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-9">
                                      <select name="level" class="form-control">
                                          <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                          <option value="1">Owner</option>
                                          <option value="2">Manajer</option>
                                          <option value="3">Bendahara</option>
                                          <option value="4">Administrator</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" name="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Simpan</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Batal</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.modal -->
            </div>
        
<!-- UNTUK EDIT DAN HAPUS -->
        <div id="ModalEdit" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        </div>

        <div id="ModalDelete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        </div>

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="assets/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="assets/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="assets/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<!-- page script -->



</body>
</html>
```

user_save.php

```html
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['nama_lengkap']) && isset($_POST['level']))
      {
       include ("connection.php");

       //ambil data
     $username    = $_POST['username'];
     $nama_lengkap     = $_POST['nama_lengkap'];
     $password   = $_POST['password'];
     $level    = $_POST['level'];
     
     $query = "insert into master_user (username, password, level, nama_lengkap, status) values ('$username', md5('$password'),'$level', '$nama_lengkap', '0')";
     if (!$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
            exit(mysqli_error($connection));
        }
       header('location:listadmin.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: question 1. why do you have 3  $(document).ready(function() in your code?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan *4

Comment: @KevinB yup 4 in 2 script tags

Comment: i dont know, i just see a tutorial and i did it, i'm a really really newbie and i study hard to make a program to my final project in college. @KevinB

Comment: @KarthikGanesan

Answer (score 0):

DataTable documentation has an example of how to create a modal Editor. I'd suggest following their example as closely as possible if you don't know what you're doing.

(https://editor.datatables.net/examples/bubble-editing/simple.html)